# PHP API JSON Response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I built a very simple JSON response to test an AJAX request from a mobile device.

I set a local domain test.local and print a json response.

```
header("Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo json_encode(array('name' => 'Julio', 'city' => 'Miami'));
```

If I access with a browser http://test.local I get:

```
{"name":"Julio","city":"Miami"}
```

But if I access with an AJAX request it prints out 'null'

```
$.ajax({
    type:     "GET",
    url:      "test.local",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.name + " " + data.city);
    }
});
```

If I change the URL in the AJAX request to 
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
works perfect.

Comment: what happens if you drop the `dataType` ?

Comment: did you try using the full URL as `http://test.local`?

Comment: Do you output anything (i.e. `var_dump`/`print`) before using `header(...)`?

Comment: @Dagon I tried drop the dataType It doesn't do anything.

Comment: @EdwinKrause I tried to add full URL and nothing happens.

Comment: @TylerSebastian Nothing, just set the header and echo out the json object.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you have is relative, the script is trying to access `/path/to/script/test.local` Add a `/` to the beginning or put `http://test.local` to make it absolute.

`$.ajax({
    type:     "GET",
    url:      "http://test.local",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data.name + " " + data.city);
    }
});`

Works for me.

Comment: I tried. But it does not print anything. Without http:// prints null, with http:// prints blank.

Comment: What does the Network tab show for Response in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: I am accessing from an emulator device running in a different computer of the "API" is responding. Does that matter ?

With .com domain is working and with the .local domain does not

Comment: Now I ran it again from the same computer that si hosting the API and it works.

Comment: Your development environment may be to blame. If I understand correctly, you are using something like VMware Player to access a PHP page running on the host machine? In that case, your test.local hostname would need to point to the IP address of the host machine. You'd need to set that up in the hosts file.

Comment: I have 2 Virtual Machines. 1 for the emulator and the other one for Web Server. I am trying the make the AJAX request from the emulator to the web server. It doesn't work, when I did the request from the web server it self it works. test,local is set in my DNS server and works perfect. If I request from any browser in any pc ion my network I can access to the JSON response.

Comment: What is the point of doing all this visualization? Most developers just develop locally on the same machine, not saying you have to, but it will make your life easier.

Comment: The first virtual machine is the Samsung TV emulator, it comes like that. The second virtual machine is my Development server it is a replica of my Production server that way I have same OS, settings, versions that my production server.